# How to reduce space above and below text in an html table heading <thead> of MVC 5 View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a table in an MVC 5 view which I would like to reduce the space above and below the text. Below is a picture of a part of the heading:

[image]

Below is the HTML I have used to try reducing the space by using negative numbers for the padding but it is not working:

```html
<table class="table  table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr style="padding-top:-4px; padding-bottom:-4px;">
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemNumber)
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VendorProductId)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Is there a way to reduce some of the space above and below the text for the heading I have? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change your <th> elements, not <tr>. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656615/padding-a-table-row

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427903/remove-all-padding-and-margin-table-html-and-css