# Why applying padding on table row doesn't work (and its a bad idea)

Tags: html, css

I was reading some posts on various blogs and also here on stack-overflow about why applying padding on `tr` doesn't work and it is also a bad idea. In practice:

```css
/*Not good*/
tr {
   padding-bottom:20px;
}

/*Correct implementation*/
th, td {
   padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Is there a specific reason because of this choice?

Source:
[Padding a table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656615/padding-a-table-row)

Comment: It would make the layout of the table very complicated. For example the borders of the cells wouldn't line up anymore, if each row would have different padding.

Comment: @RoToRa it is not the same for cells?

Comment: No, because the padding in inside the cell borders.